# Android compose preferences DataStore and manual Dependency Injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-datastore

I created a `SettingsRepository` in my `Application` class.

```
private const val USER_PREFERENCES_NAME = "myapp_preferences"
private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(
    name = USER_PREFERENCES_NAME
)

class MyApplication : Application() {
    lateinit var container: AppContainer
    lateinit var settingsRepository: SettingsRepository

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        container = DefaultAppContainer()
        settingsRepository = SettingsRepository(dataStore)
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to move this repository inside my `AppContainer` following the manual DI practices suggested in documentation, the relevant code of my `AppContainer` looks like this.-

```
private const val USER_PREFERENCES_NAME = "myapp_preferences"

interface AppContainer {
    val settingsRepository: SettingsRepository
}

class DefaultAppContainer : AppContainer {
    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(
        name = USER_PREFERENCES_NAME
    )

    override val settingsRepository: SettingsRepository by lazy {
        SettingsRepository(dataStore)
    }
}
```

But the compiler keeps complaining in this line.-

```
SettingsRepository(dataStore)
```

with an unresolved reference error for `dataStore`, more specifically:

*Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
private final val Context.dataStore: DataStore defined in com....data.DefaultAppContainer*

Since I'm kind of rusty with Kotlin, I'm guessing I'm missing a simple workaround for this, but I'm a bit lost here, any help will be much appreciated (I'm aware I could just go for `Hilt`, but I rather letting it as a last resource, as it seems a bit too much for my simple project).

Comment: The `DefaultAppContainer` should have context as a dependency and the context should be used to initialize the data store instance using `context.datastore`.